# MVC - The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-views

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I only have one class with one method in my project that looks like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Chop(this string s, int length)
    {
        ...
        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm calling this in my View like so:  **@item.PostContent.Chop(20)**
It's giving me a compiler error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Extensions.Chop(string, int)' and 'Extensions.Chop(string, int)'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If the method is static don't you have to call it on the class name? `@item.PostContent.Extensions.Chop(20)`?

Comment: I didn't think so. I was using this article as a reference: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/137/Displaying-The-First-n-Characters-Of-Text. Either way, the compiler doesn't like that...

Comment: In the article he calls the code from his view like this: `ViewData["myString"].ToString().Chop(50)`, did that not work in your case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have put your Extensions class file in an App_Code folder, is that correct? If so, move it outside of App_Code and get rid of the folder. App_Code has no place in MVC applications which by default are created as Web Application projects as opposed to Web Site projects.

Web Applications are compiled to a dll at build time, and anything in App_Code is also compiled into a separate dll at run time. Hence there being two methods and the ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did have it in App_Code. Thanks for the explanation. Works well now.